# animation does not start in canvas on android 

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I'm working on a game that requires drawing to SurfaceView's
Canvas. I'm using SurfaceHolder to obtain Canvas to draw to, and
perform drawing in a separate thread. Everything I draw displays
correctly except for this one animation.

Here is the animation definition (it is in res/drawable/
my_animation.xml:

and here is how I draw it to the Canvas:

AnimationDrawable ad = (AnimationDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_animation);
ad.draw(canvas);
ad.start();

but only the first frame ever appears on the screen.

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If I get the reference right, you have to assign your `AnimationDrawable` to an ImageView as the example from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html demonstrates:

```
// Load the ImageView that will host the animation and
// set its background to our AnimationDrawable XML resource.
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);

// Get the background, which has been compiled to an AnimationDrawable object.
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();

// Start the animation (looped playback by default).
frameAnimation.start()
```

In your case you did not assign your `AnimationDrawable` to any view so I suppose that's why it does not get updated. So you have to call `AnimationDrawable.getFrame(int)` manually.

If you are already using a separate thread why don't you involve also the code for your animation? This would render your code more consistent in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, i run into this problem too and figure out a walkaround, so i just post it here in case anyone searching about.

```java

```
final AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = ...;

final View v = new View(this) {

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        animDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }

};

animationDrawable.setCallback(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void unscheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what) {
        v.removeCallbacks(what);
    }

    @Overridew
    public void scheduleDrawable(Drawable who, Runnable what, long when) {
        v.postDelayed(what, when - SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidateDrawable(Drawable who) {
        v.postInvalidate();
    }
});
```

```

Answer (score 1):

Animated drawables of all kinds (Transition, etc.) need a `Callback` to schedule redrawals. As zhang demonstrates, it is a simple interface for posting Runnables.

To support animated drawables in a custom view, you need two things:

- pass your View to your animated Drawable's `setCallback`. Even base `View` implements `Drawable.Callback`, so there's no need to write your own wrapper.
- override `verifyDrawable` to also return true for your animated Drawable.

*As to why anyone would need that - I have just implemented animated drawable support in `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`s, how cool is that :-)*

Comment: Thank You for the solution. It works at Android 5.0 and above. But if translate transformation is applied to the canvas the solution become not working at Android 4.4 and below. To overcome the issue the invalidateDrawable method also should be overridden and request invalidation of the proper region.

Answer (score 0):

You are working with Canvas means, you are coding in low level. In low level u have to do everything. working with View (ImageView) means, it is high level.In ImageView already defined in low level on canvas how to deal with AnimationDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

Lars Blumberg's answer is correct but the documentation is incorrect; you also need to take into account this: [animation start issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1818)